# SSD Showing as two drives not one in GParted

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd

I'm not sure what happened but somewhere between removing windows and attempting to install linux my SSD has become two 64gb drives (sda and sdb), instead of the 128gb drive.

My laptops an acer s7, which is supposed to have a Toshiba 128gb drive so I don't believe there is actually two drives.

How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit] and add the output from `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like your drive just has 2 partitions on it. A partition is just a division of the drive, when you install multiple operating systems they each get their own partition (some may even have more than 1 partition).

If you no longer need one of the partitions you can delete it in Gparted, and then resize the other partition to use the full drive space. It would be wise to backup the partition before resizing it, in case of a fluke error.

You can read more about drive partitions on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning).