# Kingston SSD appears as two drives?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd

Very similar issue to this post, asking in anticipation of installing Arch for learning and whatnot.

[SSD Showing as two drives not one in GParted](https://superuser.com/questions/838024/ssd-showing-as-two-drives-not-one-in-gparted?answertab=active#tab-top)

Acer Aspire S7 with Kingston SMSR150 SSD, advertised as 128GB. Why do I see sda and sdb each having size of about half that? From what I understand, these are not partitions, but two physical devices. If this is truly the case, would you recommend a RAID config or something else?

fdisk -l gives:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 59.6GiB, etc. etc.
Units: Sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A2618D96-28AC-4A33-B6E0-DE8B09FD6A14

Disk /dev/sdb: 59.6GiB, etc. etc.
Units: Sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdc: 59.8GiB, etc. etc. (flash drive)
Units: Sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x865d48e5

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1 * 2048 125337599 125335552 59.8G c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

**~~update~~**

lsblk -S:

```
NAME HCTL TYPE VENDOR MODEL REV TRAN
sda 0:0:0:0 disk ATA Kingston SMSR150 0.47 sata
sdb 1:0:0:0 disk ATA Kingston SMSR150 0.47 sata
sdc 4:0:0:0 disk Samsung Flash Drive 1100 usb
```

thx all!

Comment: Please also include the output of **`lsblk -S` and/or `lsscsi`**.

Comment: Apparently, Acer did indeed create a proprietary SSD that has two SATA channels to a single module and uses RAID0 by default. Completely moronic, but then again – it’s Acer.

Comment: @danielb - interesting, but not moronic. If an SSD is about speed that will increase it. Quite clever actually - but yes, hard to use.